# Set value of a two dimensional array using initializer syntax

Tags: c

I am making an RPG game, and got stuck at creating the map array.

Code:

```
const int Nt;
int map[MAP_WIDTH][MAP_HEIGHT]; // global variable definition
void init() {
    //...
    map = malloc(Nt * Nt * sizeof(int)); // without this line the result is the same
    map = {
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
    };
}
```

and the compiler gives:

```
src/main.c: In function 'init':
src/main.c:114:9: error: assignment to expression with array type
  114 |     map = malloc(Nt * Nt * sizeof(int));
      |         ^
src/main.c:116:11: error: expected expression before '{' token
  116 |     map = {
      |
```

Comment: you do not neeed to malloc map, you already created it staticlly

Comment: If you want to initialize it with all zeros you could `int map[MAP_WIDTH][MAP_HEIGHT] = {0};`

Comment: You can't do `map = malloc(...);` and then try to initialize it with `map = { ... };` The latter syntax is for an _initializer_ in a _definition_ but when you do: `map = ...`, this is an _assignment_. The `{}` syntax is invalid for an assignment.

Comment: @jvx8ss this is what i have tried by the beginning, the error code is:

Comment: ```mkdir -p bin
gcc -lSDL2 -lSDL2_ttf -O3 -w -o bin/dukraft src/main.c
src/main.c: In function 'init':
src/main.c:115:11: error: expected expression before '{' token
  115 |     map = {
      |           ^
*** Error code 1

Stop.
make: stopped in /usr/home/glowiak/src/dukraft

```

Comment: @jvx8ss: If `map` is a global array (i.e. declared at file scope), which appears to be the case in OP's code, then all elements are automatically initialized to `0`. Therefore, it is not necessary to write `= {0}`. However, it is probably a good idea to write it anyway, because it does make the code clearer.

Comment: Well but the compiler still errors. How do I make it compile then?

Comment: Questions we may be making assumptions about: Are MAP_WIDTH and MAP_HEIGHT compile time constants? Where is Nt coming from  and what does it have to do with anything, since you are using MAP_WIDTH and MAP_HEIGHT? Is map (which is not a function) genuinely being defined at global scope?

Comment: @glowiak: Your entire `init` function is unnecessary, because all elements of `map` are already initialized to `0`, assuming that `map` is declared as a global array (i.e. not inside a function).

Comment: @AviBerger: since the definition of `map` is outside any function, the values of `MAP_WIDTH` and `MAP_HEIGHT` must be compile-time integer constants.  It seems odd to define `const int Nt;` — it's a funny way of storing a non-modifiable zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement:

```
int map[MAP_WIDTH][MAP_HEIGHT];
```

declares a two-dimensional array at file scope. Objects declared at file scope have static storage duration and are always initialised. In the absence of a definition, they are implicitly initialised to `0`.

From the C standard C11 6.7.9/10:

> "... If an object that has static or thread storage duration is not
> initialized explicitly, then:
>
> — if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
>
> — if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or
> unsigned) zero;"

Though, it's good practice to explicitly set it to `0`.

```
int map[MAP_WIDTH][MAP_HEIGHT] = { 0 };
```

The above statement initialises all the elements of `map` to `0`.

You could instead initialise it as:

```
int map[MAP_WIDTH][MAP_HEIGHT] = {
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
};
```

The above code assumes that `MAP_WIDTH` and `MAP_HEIGHT` are macros, and `map` is declared at file scope.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna have the initialize it, "grid" style, then you have to do it inside the declaration (assuming the HxW are macros or non-const ints):

```
int map[MAP_WIDTH][MAP_HEIGHT] = {
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
};
```

You don't use list initializers in `init()` but in declarations. As for memory management, you have to learn the difference between static allocation and dynamic memory allocation. You shouldn't do both and since you mentioned you're making an RPG, you should check other parts of your code where you might have this conflict.

Of course, you can always go down the route of using 2 loops and initialize each member to 0. Or, just do this:

```
int map[MAP_WIDTH][MAP_HEIGHT] = { 0 }; // notice the single braces
```

Comment: Regarding your last suggestion, `{ 0 }` should be `{{0}}`.  Also you are making an assumption about how `MAP_WIDTH` and `MAP_HEIGHT` are defined.   If they happen to be `const int` then the array turns out to be a VLA, and can not be initialized during declaration.

Comment: AFAIK single braces work even when not using the new nicely implemented C++11 list intiializers. GCC didn't complain either.

Comment: This works, but now I have added some stones (type 1), and it is still rendering everything grass.

Comment: You're giving us just one array as code so we can't really guess what you are doing there or how your whole game works. If you need specific help, then post everything relevant. Your post here was about initializing the array and that's what my answer and the other comments were trying to solve.